# 'AnyObject?' is not a subtype of CustomClass

Tags: ios, swift

I have a closure/block like this

```
typealias TableViewConfigureBlock = (AnyObject?, AnyObject?) -> Void
```

It takes 2 parameters: The cell object and the model object. Since I wanted it to be generic, I've used AnyObject.

When I define the block like this

```
var configureCellBlock : (ContactTableViewCell, Contact) -> Void = {cell, contactInfo in
        cell.nameLabel.text = contactInfo.name
        cell.numberLabel.text = contactInfo.number
        cell.profileImageView.image = contactInfo.image
    }
```

Compiler throws an error saying

```
'AnyObject?' is not a subtype of 'ContactTableViewCell'
```

Comment: Tried your code and it seems working fine

Comment: You don't use your `typealias` in your example. Please, add the usage, otherwise right now your code can't produce an error.

Comment: Also note that in Swift the term "generic" is actually referring to a language function that allows you to write generic templates for classes, functions, and other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `typedef` defines different parameters that your actual closure. my general example would be the following to demonstrate it:

```
typealias MyClosureType = (AnyObject?, AnyObject?) -> ()
```

the point is the closure, you defined, has to have the same interface, like:

```
var closure: MyClosureType = { (first: AnyObject?, second: AnyObject?) -> () in
    // ... 
}
```

inside the closure's body you can check the type of the parameters, like

```
let cell = first as? UITableViewCell
let contactInfo = second as? String

if cell != nil && contactInfo != nil {
    // do the tasks
} else {
    println("ops, those parameters are not what I expected")
}
```

and later you can call the block with `AnyObject` parameters, like:

```
closure(12, "SampleText");
closure(nil, ["1024", "2048"]);
```

etc, but key-point here is when you define the closure you have to keep the parameters' types as the `typealias` defines.

---

in the case of your code:

```
typealias TableViewConfigureBlock = (AnyObject?, AnyObject?) -> Void
```

vs.

```
// I'm incorrect
var configureCellBlock : TableViewConfigureBlock = { (cell: ContactTableViewCell, contactInfo: Contact) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

where the interface and the implementation have *different* types. if you write it like this, you will see how the *implementation* violates the *interface*:

```
// I'm incorrect
var configureCellBlock : (AnyObject?, AnyObject?) -> Void = { (cell: ContactTableViewCell, contactInfo: Contact) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

you'd need to do something like this here instead:

```
// I'm correct now
var configureCellBlock : (AnyObject?, AnyObject?) -> Void = { (cell: AnyObject?, contactInfo: AnyObject?) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated piece of code.

```
var configureCellBlock : TableViewConfigureBlock = ({
        (cell: AnyObject?, contact: AnyObject?) in
        var tableCell = cell as? ContactTableViewCell
        var contactInfo = contact as? Contact
        if tableCell && contactInfo {
            tableCell!.nameLabel.text = contactInfo!.name
            tableCell!.numberLabel.text = contactInfo!.number
            tableCell!.profileImageView.image = contactInfo!.image
        }
        })
```

First and foremost, you were not using the closure typealias that you had defined. As you can see I have introduced that by declaring `configureCellBlock` of type `TableViewConfigureBlock`.

Next, your closure parameter types have to match that provided in the type alias. So cell and contact have to be of type `AnyObject?`

`(cell: AnyObject?, contact: AnyObject?)`

In the body of the closure, you first have to down cast `AnyObject` type objects to the ones that can be made use of. So in the below code you do exactly that.

```
var tableCell = cell as? ContactTableViewCell
var contactInfo = contact as? Contact
```

Since the parameter are `Optional` type, you would want to check if they are nil. If they are not, you set the contact info to the corresponding cell elements.